# 'while' in async computation expression where the condition is async

Tags: asynchronous, f#, sqldatareader, sqlclient

I'm playing around with using SqlClient in F# and I'm having difficulty with using `SqlDataReader.ReadAsync`. I'm trying to do the F# equivalent of

`while (await reader.ReadAsync) { ... }`

What is the best way to do this in F#? Below is my full program. It works, but I'd like to know if there is a better way to do it.

```
open System
open System.Data.SqlClient
open System.Threading.Tasks

let connectionString = "Server=.;Integrated Security=SSPI"

module Async =
    let AwaitVoidTask : (Task -> Async<unit>) =
        Async.AwaitIAsyncResult >> Async.Ignore

    // QUESTION: Is this idiomatic F#? Is there a more generally-used way of doing this?
    let rec While (predicateFn : unit -> Async<bool>) (action : unit -> unit) : Async<unit> = 
        async {
            let! b = predicateFn()
            match b with
                | true -> action(); do! While predicateFn action
                | false -> ()
        }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let work = async {
        // Open connection
        use conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
        do! conn.OpenAsync() |> Async.AwaitVoidTask

        // Execute command
        use cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText <- "select name from sys.databases"
        let! reader = cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

        // Consume reader

        // I want a convenient 'while' loop like this...
        //while reader.ReadAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask do // Error: This expression was expected to have type bool but here has type Async<bool>
        //    reader.GetValue 0 |> string |> printfn "%s"
        // Instead I used the 'Async.While' method that I defined above.

        let ConsumeReader = Async.While (fun () -> reader.ReadAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask)
        do! ConsumeReader (fun () -> reader.GetValue 0 |> string |> printfn "%s")
    }
    work |> Async.RunSynchronously
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is one issue in your code which is that you're doing a recursive call using
`do! While predicateFn action`. This is a problem because it does not turn into a tail-call and so you could end up with memory leaks. The right way to do this is to use `return!` instead of `do!`.

Aside from that, your code works good. But you can actually extend the `async` computation builder to let you use ordinary `while` keyword. To do that, you need a slightly different version of `While`:

```
let rec While (predicateFn : unit -> Async<bool>) (action : Async<unit>) : Async<unit> = 
    async {
        let! b = predicateFn()
        if b then
            do! action
            return! While predicateFn action
    }

type AsyncBuilder with
    member x.While(cond, body) = Async.While cond body
```

Here, the body is also asynchronous and it is not a function. Then we add a `While` method to the computation builder (so we are adding another overload as an extension method). With this, you can actually write:

```
 while Async.AwaitTask(reader.ReadAsync()) do // This is async!
     do! Async.Sleep(1000)   // The body is asynchronous too
     reader.GetValue 0 |> string |> printfn "%s"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do the same as you.  If you can stomach refs though, you can shorten it to

```
let go = ref true
while !go do
  let! more = reader.ReadAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
  go := more
  reader.GetValue 0 |> string |> printfn "%s"
```